# Preciso que um item do meu select fique selecionado, Angular

Tags: angularjs, html5, select

Tenho um componente select

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Entidade:</label> 
        <select ng-model="distrito.entidade.idEntidade" class="form-control">
        <option value="{{dis.entidade.idEntidade}}" ng-repeat="dis in distritos">{{dis.entidade.nome}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Minha classe controller

```
app.controller("buscaDistritoController", function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.distritos = [];
    $scope.distrito = {}; // binding com o form

    carregarDistritos = function() {

        token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");


        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/distritos'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.distritos = response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });
    };



    $scope.salvarDistritos = function() {
        if ($scope.frmDistrito.$valid) {
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/distritos',
                data : $scope.distrito
            }).then(function(response) {
                carregarDistritos();
                $scope.distrito = {};

            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(response.status);
            });

        } else {
             alert("Campos com * são de preenchimento obrigatório");

        }
    };

    $scope.excluirDistritos = function(distrito) {
        bootbox.confirm({
            message : "Deseja excluir o registro permanentemente ?",
            buttons : {
                cancel : {
                    label : '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar'
                },
                confirm : {
                    label : '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Sim'
                }
            },
            callback : function(result) {
                if (result == true) {
                    $http({
                        method : 'DELETE',
                        url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/distritos/'+distrito.id
                    }).then(function(response) {

                        pos = $scope.distritos.indexOf(distrito);
                        $scope.distritos.splice(pos, 1);

                    }, function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        console.log(response.status);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.alterarDistritos = function(dis) {
        $scope.distrito = angular.copy(dis);
    };

    $scope.cancelarAlteracaoDistritos = function() {
        $scope.distrito = {};
    };

    carregarDistritos();

});
```

Quero que fique sempre uma opção selecionada, Atualmente mostra somente uma opção visível dentro do select e outras opções que estão em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que eu preciso é exatamente isso mas somente com uma opção e sempre essa opção selecionada e sem a repetição dos selects é claro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite sua questão e coloque o seu controller por favor, só com isso não consigo ajudar

Comment: @Jackson Pergunta editada !

Comment: Ok @Eduardo, qual o response da API?

Comment: @Jackson o response é via JSON de um array de entidades

Comment: @Jackson eu reeditei a pergunta ali.. talvez ficou melhor de entender o que eu preciso.

Comment: eu entendi o que queres, você pode me passar o que vem da sua chamada HTTP Request? O que vem do http://localhost:8080/user/distritos ?

Comment: Recebo um Array de Json

`{idDistrito: 3, nome: "Distrito de Taquari", codigoDne: "00002454", flagAtivo: 1, entidade: {…}, …}

{idDistrito: 45, nome: "testeee", codigoDne: "00000009", flagAtivo: null, entidade: 1, …}

{idDistrito: 46, nome: "salvando distrito", codigoDne: "000008", flagAtivo: null, entidade: 1, …}`

Comment: Respondi a pergunta com um plunker , eu fiz a estrutura JSON fixa supondo em como seria ela. Porque o JSON aí não está completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eduardo**,

O ideal para utilizar nesse caso é o `ng-options`, ele é um componente do AngularJS feito especialmente para popular um `Select`. 
De qualquer maneira, seu `NG-MODEL` vem zerado por padrão, você precisa inicializar ele para ele vir algo selecionado.

[Plunker Exemplo usando NG-OPTIONS](https://plnkr.co/edit/iIFzMIoQl4ALN1oOBGPL?p=preview)

Leia mais sobre [ng-options aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Qualquer dúvida estou à disposição.